# how to fix hamming weight invariants

Tags: bit-manipulation, dafny, loop-invariant

I am learning Dafny, attempting to write a specification for the hamming weight problem, aka the number of 1 bits in a number. I believe I have gotten the specification correct, but it still doesn't verify. For speed of verification I limited it to 8 bit numbers;
problem definition: https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-1-bits/

```
function method twoPow(x: bv16): bv16
  requires 0 <= x <= 16
{
  1 << x
}

function method oneMask(n: bv16): bv16
    requires 0 <= n <= 16
    ensures oneMask(n) == twoPow(n)-1
{
   twoPow(n)-1
}

function countOneBits(n:bv8): bv8 {
    if n == 0 then 0 else (n & 1) + countOneBits(n >> 1)
}

method hammingWeight(n: bv8) returns (count: bv8 )
    ensures count == countOneBits(n)
{
    count := 0;
    var i := 0;
    var n' := n;
    assert oneMask(8) as bv8 == 255; //passes
    while i < 8
        invariant 0 <= i <= 8
        invariant n' == n >> i
        invariant count == countOneBits(n & oneMask(i) as bv8);
    {
        count := count + n' & 1;
        n' := n' >> 1;
        i := i + 1;
    }
}
```

I have written the same code in javascript to test the behavior and example the invariant values before and after the loop. I don't seen any problems.

```
function twoPow(x) {
    return 1 << x;
}

function oneMask(n) {
    return twoPow(n)-1;
}

function countOneBits(n) {
    return n === 0 ? 0 : (n & 1) + countOneBits(n >> 1)
}

function hammingWeight(n) {
    if(n < 0 || n > 256) throw new Error("out of range")
    console.log(`n: ${n} also ${n.toString(2)}`)
    let count = 0;
    let i = 0;
    let nprime = n;
    console.log("beforeloop",`i: ${i}`, `n' = ${nprime}`, `count: ${count}`, `oneMask: ${oneMask(i)}`, `cb: ${countOneBits(n & oneMask(i))}`)
    console.log("invariants", i >= 0 && i <= 8, nprime == n >> i, count == countOneBits(n & oneMask(i)));
    while (i < 8) {
        console.log("");
        console.log('before',`i: ${i}`, `n' = ${nprime}`, `count: ${count}`, `oneMask: ${oneMask(i)}`, `cb: ${countOneBits(n & oneMask(i))}`)
        console.log("invariants", i >= 0 && i <= 8, nprime == n >> i, count == countOneBits(n & oneMask(i)));
        count += nprime & 1;
        nprime = nprime >> 1;
        i++;
        console.log('Afterloop',`i: ${i}`, `n' = ${nprime}`, `count: ${count}`, `oneMask: ${oneMask(i)}`, `cb: ${countOneBits(n & oneMask(i))}`)
        console.log("invariants", i >= 0 && i <= 8, nprime == n >> i, count == countOneBits(n & oneMask(i)));
    }
    return count;
};

hammingWeight(128);
```

All invariants evaluate as true. I must be missing something. it says `invariant count == countOneBits(n & oneMask(i) as bv8);` might not be maintained by the loop. Running the javascript shows that they are all true. Is it due to the cast of oneMask to bv8?

edit:
I replaced the mask function with one that didn't require casting and that still not resolve the problem.

```
function method oneMaskOr(n: bv8): bv8 
    requires 0 <= n <= 8
    ensures oneMaskOr(n) as bv16 == oneMask(n as bv16)
{
    if n == 0 then 0 else (1 << (n-1)) | oneMaskOr(n-1)
}
```

One interesting thing I found is that it shows me a counter example where it has reached the end of the loop and the final bit of the input variable n is set, so values 128 or greater. But when I add an assertion above the loop that value equals the count at the end of the loop it then shows me the another value of n.

```
assert 1 == countOneBits(128 & OneMaskOr(8)); //counterexample -> 192
assert 2 == countOneBits(192 & OneMaskOr(8)); //counterexample -> 160
```

So it seems like it isn't evaluating the loop invariant after the end of loop? I thought the whole point of the invariants was to evaluate after the end of loop.

Edit 2:
I figured it out, apparently adding the explicit decreases clause to the while loop fixed it. I don't get it though. I thought Dafny could figure this out.

```
    while i < 8
        invariant 0 <= i <= 8
        invariant n' == n >> i
        invariant count == countOneBits(n & oneMask(i) as bv8);
        decreases 8 - i
    {
```

I see one line in the [docs](https://dafny-lang.github.io/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef.html#sec-loop-termination) for loop termination saying

> If the decreases clause of a loop specifies *, then no termination check will be performed. Use of this feature is sound only with respect to partial correctness.

So is if the decreases clause is missing does it default to `*`?

Comment: I dug into the original a bit and was not able to fully understand why it doesn't pass. One thing I noticed is that if you don't explicitly state a decreases clause, the inferred clause is `8 as int - i as int`. And if you state this clause explicitly, the proof still doesn't work (as expected). I'm not sure why the casts in the decreases clause are causing problems down the line though.

Comment: Also, it's not that relevant to this question, but I never miss an opportunity to point out that just because a loop invariant is true doesn't mean Dafny will prove it! See the [FAQ](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ#my-program-is-correct-but-dafny-says-there-is-a-problem-what-gives) and the [Guide](https://dafny-lang.github.io/dafny/OnlineTutorial/guide#assertions). It is basically never correct to think "well the assertions are true at runtime, therefore there is a bug in dafny."

Comment: Well that is a sobering fact although I felt like my invariants where pretty simple. If the state space is explorable, like it is in this case, then will Dafny be able to prove the invariants? 

I understand that Dafny cannot prove most things by itself. In this case all the variables were concrete and accessible to dafny, and I wasn't checking anything more difficult than numerical equality. So is that generally safe or will some equality expressions of primitive types need lemma support?

Comment: If the state space is finite, then in principle there's no reason why Dafny couldn't just explore it. But that's not how Dafny works, because Dafny is designed primarily for use cases where the state space is either infinite or so large that it would not be feasible to explore. This does have the downside that in very simple situations, Dafny is not as smart as it could be. But the upside is that Dafny scales to hard verification problems.

Comment: From what I can tell, the problem is that the verifier is not very good at conversions between bitvectors and integers. I tried writing some lemmas that could be used in your program, but even getting them through was tough. However, by changing bitvectors to `nat` and using `*`, `/`, and `%`, I can easily prove the program to be correct.

Comment: Could you share those lemmas and/or the nat version of the program? Particularly I am interested in verifying quite a few bit vector programs for some 8 bit assembly programming I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around, I did find a version which passes though it required reworking `countOneBits()` so that its recursion followed the order of iteration:

```dafny
function countOneBits(n:bv8, i: int, j:int): bv8
  requires i ≥ 0 ∧ i ≤ j ∧ j ≤ 8
  decreases 8-i {
  if i == j then 0
  else (n&1) + countOneBits(n >> 1, i+1, j)
}

method hammingWeight(n: bv8) returns (count: bv8 )
ensures count == countOneBits(n,0,8)
{
    count ≔  0;
    var i ≔  0;
    var n' ≔ n;
    //
    assert count == countOneBits(n,0,i);
    //
    while i < 8
        invariant 0 ≤ i ≤ 8;
        invariant n' == n >> i;
        invariant count == countOneBits(n,0,i);
    {
        count ≔  (n' & 1) + count;
        n' ≔  n' >> 1;
        i ≔  i + 1;
    }
}
```

The intuition here is that `countOneBits(n,i,j)` returns the number of `1` bits between `i` (inclusive) and `j` (exclusive).  This then reflects what the loop is doing as we increase `i`.

Comment: For some reason, changing `decreases 8-i` to decreases `j-i` caused it to fail which confused me for a while.